ASUS DRAM light preventing boot
Recently I've been faced with a problem that caught me by surprise. An hour before the problem started I finished up setting up my PC in my new apartment and was ready to start getting everything configured to my liking. In my old apartment, it was working perfectly fine but as soon as I moved, everything changed. I realized that the PC had the DRAM light on and was refusing to turn on even though it was taking power, which caused a slight heart attack because this is my first PC build. I've read on the ASUS website to "try to boot with only one memory installed, then reboot each time with an additional memory installed." So I've done that and realized that my PC luckily works with two sticks of RAM, but then my other two completely step me back to square one. I really would like to keep my setup the way that it was so is there any tips of what I should do?
Motherboard: Asus ROG STRIX B550-F GAMING ATX AM4 Motherboard
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 3.7 GHz 6-Core Processor
Cooler: Corsair iCUE H115i ELITE CAPELLIX 97 CFM Liquid CPU Cooler
RAM: Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16 Memory x2
Storage: Samsung 970 Evo Plus 2 TB M.2-2280 PCIe 3.0 X4 NVME Solid State Drive
GPU: Asus TUF GAMING OC GeForce RTX 3080 12GB LHR 12 GB Video Card
Power Supply: Corsair RM750 750 W 80+ Gold Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply
I do not know if I need to give anymore information but I will if needed.

While on a state where the system will be POST, update the firmware, to the current version. You have confirmed each module allows the system to boot individually? Memory errors like you describe could also be caused by your processor being improperly installed and/or damaged (bent pins).

@Ramhound, I've updated bios to the latest version for my computer, and I need to also update my GPU to its latest version but I dont think that would cause issues... also you think it might be the processor? because i've had this PC for over two full years and it hasn't given me a problem until now.

Updating your display driver won’t solve your current issue.

yeahhhh, thats why i avoided it, but for some reason it still is giving me the same problems, even though the DDR4 Ram sticks are receiving power, just not letting the PC boot @Ramhound

I will go back to the CPU could be the problem
